# Spark: run InputFormat as singleton

Tags: database, hadoop, apache-spark

I'm trying to integrate a key-value database to Spark and have some questions.
I'm a Spark beginner, have read a lot and run some samples but nothing too
complex.

**Scenario**:

I'm using a small hdfs cluster to store incoming messages in a database.
The cluster has 5 nodes, and the data is split into 5 partitions. Each
partition is stored in a separate database file. Each node can therefore process
its own partition of the data.

**The Problem**:

The interface to the database software is based on JNI, the database itself is
implemented in C. For technical reasons, the database software can maintain
only one active connection at a time. There can be only one JVM process which
is connected to the Database.

Because of this limitation, reading from and writing to the database must go
through the same JVM process.

(Background info: the database is embedded into the process. It's file based,
and only one process can open it at a time. I *could* let it run in a separate
process, but that would be slower because of the IPC overhead. My application
will perform many full table scans. Additional writes will be batched and are
not time-critical.)

**The Solution**:

I have a few ideas in my mind how to solve this, but i don't know if they work
well with Spark.

- Maybe it's possible to magically configure Spark to only have one instance of my
  proprietary InputFormat per node.
- If my InputFormat is used for the first time, it starts a separate thread
  which will create the database connection. This thread will then continue
  as a daemon and will live as long as the JVM lives. This will only work
  if there's just one JVM per node. If Spark starts multiple JVMs on the
  same node then each would start its own database thread, which would not
  work.
- Move my database connection to a separate JVM process per node, and my
  InputFormat then uses IPC to connect to this process. As i said, i'd like to avoid this.
- Or maybe you have another, better idea?

My favourite solution would be #1, followed closely by #2.

Thanks for any comment and answer!

Comment: I went for #3 because #1 and #2 seem to be not possible.

Answer (score 1):

I believe the best option here is to connect to your DB from driver, not from executors. This part of the system anyway would be a bottleneck.

Answer (score 0):

Have you thought of queueing (buffer) then using spark streaming to dequeue and use your output format to write.

Answer (score 0):

If data from your DB fits into RAM memory of your spark-driver you can load it there as a collection and then parallelize it to an RDD https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.2.0/rdd-programming-guide.html#parallelized-collections